# Ordinal addition is not commutative

Tags: ordinals

The simplest example is $$1+\omega=\omega \neq \omega +1$$

But I think it is also true that $$\omega ^\alpha+\omega^\beta=\omega ^\beta$$ for general ordinals $\alpha < \beta$ but I don't know how to prove this.

In fact I don't even know how to prove $1+\omega^2=\omega^2$.

I've tried induction on $\beta$:

If $\beta=\sup(\lambda| \lambda <\beta)$ is a limit, then given $\alpha<\beta$, we have $$\omega^\alpha+\omega^\lambda=\omega^\lambda$$ for all $\alpha<\lambda<\beta$. Taking sups, we get
$$\omega^\alpha+\omega^\beta=\sup(\omega^\alpha+\omega^\lambda)=\sup(\omega^\lambda)=\omega^\beta$$

If $\beta=\hat{\beta}^+ $ is a successor, and $\alpha<\hat{\beta}$ then $$\omega^\alpha+\omega^{\hat{\beta}}=\omega^{\hat{\beta}}$$ implies
$$\omega^{\alpha^+}+\omega^\beta=\omega^\beta$$
because ordinal multiplication is left-distributive. This still leaves $\alpha=0$ and $\alpha=\hat{\beta}$ which I don't know how to do.

Comment: It is correct, but no idea how to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove in general that if $\beta \ge \alpha\cdot \omega$, then $\alpha+\beta=\beta$.

The easiest way is probably to write $\beta=\alpha\cdot\omega+\delta$, and then construct ordered sets of order type $\alpha+\alpha\cdot\omega+\delta$ and $\alpha\cdot\omega+\delta$ and show an order isomorphism between them. The $\delta$ parts maps to each other; mapping $\alpha+\alpha\cdot\omega$ to $\alpha\cdot\omega$ can be done by increasing the second entry in each pair in $\alpha\cdot\omega$ by one and map the $\alpha$ part to $\alpha\times\{0\}$.

Expressing this with purely syntactic induction arguments looks like it's going to be complex, but nobody says you *have to* do that if you have shown once and for all that the order-type interpretations of ordinal arithmetic work.

Comment: The first statement is in fact an "if and only if".